# Cоздание поля в существующей таблице и заполнение его данными - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Есть две таблицы:

1. **Владельцы животных**: информация о владельцах животных
2. **Животные**: в формате "`IDвладельца` - `IDживотного` - `приоритет животного`"

Необходимо добавить в табл.1 поле `Главное животное`, куда записывается `IDживотного`, найденного в табл.2 по максимальному приоритету.

Вопрос как добавить поле не стоит, вопрос как выбрать `IDживотного` с макс приоритетом - тоже.

Вопрос в том, в каком виде (процедура, функция) и каким образом провести одноразовое заполнение таким образом созданного поля для всех владельцев? То есть, подскажите, пожалуйста, аналог `foreach ID in table1 ....`

Comment: А почему нельзя просто создать поле, и заполнить его одним запросом?

Comment: что имеется в виду? в смысле, я понимаю, как заполнить поле для одной записи - получается конструкция с if exists и т.д., а как сделать это для всех записей?

Comment: Я могу ошибиться в синтаксисе, но примерно так UPDATE 'Владельцы животных' tvlad JOIN (SELECT IDвладельца,  IDживотного, приоритет животного FROM Животные GROUP BY IDвладельца HAVING MAX(приоритет животного)) tpets SET tvlad.'Главное животное' = tpets.'IDживотного' WHERE tvlad.IDвладельца = tpets.IDвладельца

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Добавьте примеры что ли.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже сказали в комментариях, для выполнения задачи достаточно одного единственного запроса, без каких-либо циклов. Как-то так, например:

```sql
UPDATE [Владельцы животных] 
SET [Главное животное] = t.main
FROM (SELECT [IDвладельца], MAX([приоритет животного]) AS main 
    FROM [Животные] 
    GROUP BY [IDвладельца]
) AS t
WHERE t.[IDвладельца] = [Владельцы животных].[IDвладельца]
```